# How to keep folder of bucket b1 in sync with bucket b2 in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I have storage buckets b1 and b2 in google cloud. b2 has a folder f1, I need to maintain f1 in sync with bucket b2. I came across the gsutil's rsync command, but that doesn't solve my problem.

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fully automated solution (that you implement with code you write), use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to [write a storage trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) the runs when a new object is created in b1, then copy it to b2.  You would probably also want to trigger on the deletion of objects as well in order to mirror that change.

You will have to write the code for all this - there is no fully-managed solution provided by Cloud Functions.